# Z3 timeout after replacement of uninterpreted sort to Int

Tags: z3

For formula with uninterpreted sort `B` Z3 prints `unsat` but when I replace sort `B` to `Int` it prints `timeout`(second script). I would like to understand the reason for it.

first:

```
(declare-sort A)
(declare-sort B)
(declare-fun f (B) A)
(declare-fun f-inv (A) B)
(declare-const b0 B)
(declare-const b1 B)

(assert (forall ((x B)) (= (f-inv (f x)) x)))
(assert (not (= (f b0) (f b1))))

(check-sat)
```

second:

```
(declare-sort A)
(declare-fun f (Int) A)
(declare-fun f-inv (A) Int)

(assert (forall ((x Int)) (= (f-inv (f x)) x)))
(assert (not (= (f 0) (f 1))))

(check-sat)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Z3 is not able to decide neither "first" and "second".

For "first" I am obtaining :   "sat".

For "first" when the line

```
(assert (not (= (f b0) (f b1))))
```

is replaced by

```
(assert  (= (f b0) (f b1)))
```

the result is "sat".  In other words Z3 is not able to decide "first".  The effective result from Z3 is "timeout" for "first" and "second".

Z3 has problems with combinations of uninterpreted functions.

Do you agree?

Comment: What do you mean by 'effective'? In the first case right answer is `sat` as well as in the second case. Model for 1: b0 != b1. Model for 2: b0 = b1. So `timeout` isn't correct here. I think that `timeout` for second case arises because of `Int` is infinite sort but I'd like to get more detailed answer.

Comment: You are right is very interesting to know what is the deep reason for the "timeout".  All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Both versions are now `sat` when tried online on [Compsys tools](https://compsys-tools.ens-lyon.fr/z3/).